# SQL Select, different color depending on result number

Tags: php, sql, css, select, html

I have an SQL SELECT statement and after executing this I have a While statement to display every record in a div. These div are all under one another and I want the divs to alternate in color. So like this:

```
Result 1 = white div
Result 2 = grey div
Result 3 = white div
Result 4 = grey div.
```

I actually have no idea how to accomplish this, anyone who could help me?
Thanks!

EDIT: I can actually come up with the theory do to this, even numbers white, uneven numbers grey, but how do I code this?

Comment: I guess take every odd result value and make it white, and make every even result value grey. You would need an if statement and would have to use the modulus operator %.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it just with css, like this:

```
.resultdiv:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: white;
}

.resultdiv:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: grey;
}
```

This will work just make sure you add `class="resultdiv"` to all divs you create in the while loop.

Comment: And how do I determine whether a row is even or uneven?

Comment: You don't have to determine it, it's done automatically, you just append divs, the browser will know which ones are odd/even and apply the css style accordingly.

Comment: Oké, big thanks. Had no idea that CSS supported this kind of thing!

Comment: Careful! nth-child is not supported in IE8 and below. If you want a javascript solution that is cross-browser compatible you can take a look at this jQuery tutorial: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Zebra_Striping_Made_Easy

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to alter colours.

Start it with white, when printing a result use the colour on the variable and change it to the other colour (change it to white when it's gray and to gray when it's white).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a boolean variable in your while loop where you are fetching the result set to determine if the row is even or odd and based on that change the color of your DIV.

Example:

```
$alt_row = false;

while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
{

    $alt_row = (!$alt_row) ? true : false;

    if ($alt_row) {
        echo '<div class="alt">Content</div>';  
    } else {
        echo '<div>Content</div>';
    }
}
```

I'm not a fan of mixing my logic and presentation code though.